# Ubuntu 22.04.3 VM in Windows WSL2: set mouse pointer size for GUI apps

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mouse-pointer

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux v2 (WSL2) to run Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Windows 11 host.  See also:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview

When I invoke GUI apps within the Ubuntu VM—e.g., meld, gvim, etc., the GUI apps look fine: the windows are appropriately sized, the toolbar icons are the correct size, the text elements (e.g., menus) are sized correctly and readable, etc.  However, the mouse pointer is always absurdly small. It doesn't matter which GUI application I invoke—i.e., this happens for GTK and non-GTK apps.

[*Note 1*. The mouse pointer is sufficiently sized—not too small or too large—when the pointer is positioned over a native Windows app window. *–end note*]

I've tried installing the package `big-cursor` on the Ubuntu VM, but the following command line does not change the mouse pointer size when the mouse is positioned above a GUI Linux app window (e.g., meld):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48
```

[*Note 2*. After I issued the above command line I exited the VM, I shut down the VM via a Windows PowerShell command prompt, I waited 10 seconds, and then I restarted the VM. *–end note*]

Does anyone know how to change/specify the mouse pointer's size in this situation?

Comment: Your set up is not clear to me. WSL2 is itself a VM of sorts. Are you modifying the Ubuntu installation in WSL or are you running a VM inside the WSL VM? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499344/edit) and add the details of how you setup Ubuntu in a VM within WSL2.